# Constraint broke UIButton on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, constraints

I have a universal app using auto layout, but for unknown reason, the constraint I have on the `UIButton` is causing the button to not respond on iPhone (works perfectly fine on iPad). Below is the snapshot of my .xib view that will eventually get embedded inside another `UIScrollView`.

[image]

Note that *"(read drug facts...)"* is my standard `UIButton` that doesn't respond to click on iPhone. However, when I changed the top spacing between *Dose* label and *Body View*, then it responded to clicks. But, when I reduced the spacing constant from 40 down to 10 then the button won't respond anymore. I don't see view that is invisibly hiding the button.

**UPDATE 1:**
Thanks Matt for reminding me of the great view debugging feature which I've forgotten about. Even with the view debugging, I'm unable to find its culprit. Please see images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run the app and use View Debugging.